# How to skip queries if table doesn't exits in Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, unix, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have a .sql file in which there are 100s of queries and im spooling their output in a single file but some of tables doesn't exits in Oracle database, so I want to skip those queries and proceed to next query whose table is present on database.

Comment: That's what it will do by default. Hiding the ORA-00942 errors is the hard part.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Are you looking for `WHENEVER SQLERROR continue`? https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve052.htm#SQPUG135

Comment: Why do you keep those SELECTs if they don't fetch anything because tables don't exist? If you clean the script up, maybe you wouldn't have "100s" but "10s" of queries.

Comment: @Littlefoot I don't know whose table exits or not, if there is any easy way to find whether table exits then only continue like we have in hive then that will work

Answer (score 0):

You can use following sql*plus command in your script.

whenever sqlerror continue

Then if your script is hitting any sql error like "table or view doesn't exits" then it will skip and execute next query from script. I hope this will help you. Have a nice day.